# How do I correctly use the SendBulkTemplatedEmailRequest from SES in the AWS-SDK-NET?

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-sdk-net

I am attempting to use the **AmazonSimpleEmailService** client via the **AWS-SDK for .Net**, to send a **SendBulkTempatedEmailRequest**. I have implemented a dedicated handler for actually building the request and making the **SendBulkTemplatedEmailAsync** call. It is not working as I expect. I think there is a bug with how the request object is serialized and passed to the API.

Here is some sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Amazon.SimpleEmail;
using Amazon.SimpleEmail.Model;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Sample.AWS.SES
{
  public class SendEmailService
  {   
    private readonly IAmazonSimpleEmailService _sesClient;

    public SendEmailService(IAmazonSimpleEmailService sesClient)
    {
      _sesClient = sesClient;
    }

    public async Task<string> SendBulkEmailAsync(SesOrderCreatedBulkTemplate data)
    {
      var result = string.Empty;
      var request = new SendBulkTemplatedEmailRequest
      {
        Template = data.Template,
        ConfigurationSetName = data.ConfigurationSet,
        DefaultTemplateData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data.DefaultTemplateData),
        Source = data.Source,
        Destinations = data.Destinations
          .Select(d => new BulkEmailDestination
          {
            Destination = new Destination
            {
              ToAddresses = d.ToAddresses.ToList(),
            },
            ReplacementTemplateData = string.Empty
          })
          .ToList(),
        ReplyToAddresses = data.ReplyToAddresses.ToList()
      };

      try
      {
        var resp = await _sesClient.SendBulkTemplatedEmailAsync(request);
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        var msgEx = new Exception("Error sending message to SES.", ex);
        throw msgEx;
      }
      return result;
    }

    public class SesOrderCreatedBulkTemplate
    {
      public string Source { get; set; }
      public string Template { get; set; }
      public string ConfigurationSet { get; set; }
      public IEnumerable<Destination> Destinations { get; set; }
      public MyTemplateData DefaultTemplateData { get; set; }
      public IEnumerable<string> ReplyToAddresses { get; set; }
      public string ReturnPath { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }

    public class DestinationObj
    {
      public IEnumerable<string> ToAddresses { get; set; }
      public MyTemplateData ReplacementTemplateData { get; set; }

      public DestinationObj() {}
    }

    public class MyTemplateData
    {
      public List<Person> Tenants { get; set; }
    }

    public class Person
    {
      public string PersonName { get; set; }
      public List<object> PersonData { get; set; }
    }
  }
}
```

The properties for `SourceArn`, `TemplateArn` and `ReturnPathArn` are omitted on purpose.  According the [SES documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-the-api.html), the SDK wraps the low-level functionality of the Amazon SES API with higher-level data types and function calls that take care of the details for you. When I view the [API documentation for sending bulk email](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference/API_SendBulkTemplatedEmail.html), the ARN properties are all list as **not required**. When I look at the some [CLI examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-personalized-email-api.html), it is the same. When I look at the documentation for the [SDK for .Net v3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/SimpleEmail/TSendBulkTemplatedEmailRequest.html), it is ambiguous (not marked as required or optional).

Because the SDK supposed to wrap the low-level functionality of the API, I do not believe the ARN values are required (neither the API nor the CLI require them). However, when I attempt to actually use the request object created in the code snippet, I get an error that says `InvalidTemplateData`.

***If I serialize the request object to JSON, then remove the 3 ARN fields from the string, I can use either the API or the CLI to successfully send the message.***

In addition to not specifying a value for the ARN's, I have tried (for all 3 ARN values):

`specificArn = string.empty;`
`specificArn = new {};`
`specificArn = "";`

I have also tried explicitly newing-up the object separate from initializing the properties:
`var request = new SendBulkTemplatedEmailRequest();`, and then individually populating the properties.

If I don't initialize the ARN values, I get an error about **NoneType** vs **StringType** when the send method is called. The variations on string initialization that I tried result in **InvalidTemplateData** errors.

Note, I do know ARN values for Source and ReturnPath. I do not have an ARN value for the template we use. Supposedly, using the CLI, when you create a template you should receive a response back that includes the ARN for the template. I get no response from the CLI when I create a template, but it does get created every time I try. The `describe-template` CLI command is not valid when you specify SES and responds with an error if I don't specify the workspace (whatever you call the SES space) value.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I was able to verify with AWS that there was a bug in the SDK for .Net. I switched to using the API instead of the SDK for our solution.

Answer (score 1):

From the provided code it's hard to say what you pass into API.

This is how I send bulk emails:

#### SES configuration

- create a template (taken from `AWS SES` docs) and save it to a file - `my-template.json`

```json
{
  "Template": {
    "TemplateName": "my-template",
    "SubjectPart": "Greetings, {{name}}!",
    "HtmlPart": "<h1>Hello {{name}},</h1><p>Your favorite animal is {{favoriteanimal}}.</p>",
    "TextPart": "Dear {{name}},\r\nYour favorite animal is {{favoriteanimal}}."
  }
}
```

- create a template via CLI  `aws ses create-template --cli-input-json file://my-template.json`

#### SES .NET SDK API

```cs
async Task SendAsync(string[] receivers)
{
    var destinations = receivers
        .Select(receiver => new BulkEmailDestination
        {
            Destination = new Destination(new List<string> { receiver }),
            ReplacementTemplateData = ToJson(receiver, "Doggy")
        })
        .ToList();
    
    var bulkTemplate = new SendBulkTemplatedEmailRequest
    {
        Source = "your-email@gmail.com", // your email you bulk send from
        Template = "my-template",        // your template name
        DefaultTemplateData = ToJson("<not set>", "<not set>"),
        Destinations = destinations
    };
    await _client.SendBulkTemplatedEmailAsync(bulkTemplate);
}

// Create replacement data by serializing Dictionary
string ToJson(string name, string favoriteanimal)
    => JsonSerializer.Serialize(new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "name", name },
        { "favoriteanimal", favoriteanimal }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks @Semuserable. I was missing DefaultTemplate from SendBulkTemplatedEmailRequest object and aws sdk wasn't been able to send the mails without that. Why do they even need that default template?
By the way, debugger can be your friend if you need to see what the SendBulkTemplatedEmailAsync() returns. It can help. Happy coding!